# CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync not working for Samsung S6

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin Forms app I use the Media Plugin to take photos. The code I use works fine on a Moto G 3rd Gen however when I run the same code on a Samsung S6 the file returned is always null and the camera isn't started.

I have upgraded to the the pre release of the plugin (2.4.0), but I still get the same result.

This is my TakePhoto method :-

```
    public async Task TakePhoto()
    {
        var result = await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

        if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
        {
            _analyticsService.TagEvent("AndroidCameraService : Camera Not Available");
        }
        else
        {
            var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
            {
                DefaultCamera = CameraDevice.Rear,
                Directory = "Test",
                Name = "Original.jpg",
                PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Full,
                SaveToAlbum = false
            });

            if (file == null)
            {
                _analyticsService.TagEvent("AndroidCameraService : File Null");
            }
            else
            {
                var rotationNeeded = GetNeededRotation(file.Path);

                ResizeImage(file.Path, file.Path.Replace("Original", "Resized"), 320, 240);

                var byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(file.Path.Replace("Original", "Resized"));

                PhotoAsBase64String = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);

                CleanUpFiles(file.Path);
            }
        }
    }
```

I am not sure why this isn't working on the Samsung S6 when it works another device.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?  I just started experiencing the same issue on a Nexus 6P.

Comment: I discovered that permissions for my app are not changing for the camera, even when I select allow camera.  This is the cause...still looking for the solution.  Will post if I find it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an issue related to an update with Marshmallow.  Now, I have to explicitly request camera and filesystem access from my app; the plugin won't do it correctly.  Once I give the app permissions, then the plugin works as expected.  It's not ideal since the plugin is supposed to do this for us, but that's how I got it to work.